# Нужна помощь с автоматизацией удаления бэкапов

Tags: резервное-копирование

Нужно автоматизировать удаление бэкапа после завершения задачи в Veeam backup & replication. Но суть в том, что Veeam установлен на одном компе, а бэкапы используются на удаленном другом компе, то есть мне надо, чтобы на моем компе, где установлен Veeam, была автоматизировано удаление бэкапов с другого, удаленного компа.
В самом Veeam не нашел такой настройки, а через планировщик получается костыль, который работает через раз, думал нужен скрипт, но не знаю как его написать.
Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой или может написать скрипт, помогите пожалуйста.